# KornShell - Test with variable that may be not set

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I have the following code in KornShell (ksh):

```
FAILURE=1
SUCCESS=0

isNumeric(){

    if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        case $1 in
            *[!0-9]* | "")  return $FAILURE;
                       * )  return $SUCCESS;
        esac;
    else
        return $FAILURE;
    fi;
}

#...
FILE_EXT=${FILE#*.}

if [ isNumeric ${FILE_EXT} ]; then
    echo "Numbered file."
fi
#...
```

In some cases the file name not have an extension, and this causes the `FILE_EXT` variable to be empty, which causes the following error:
`./script[37]: test: 0403-004 Specify a parameter with this command.`

How should I be calling this function so that I do not get this error?

Comment: I would expect the whole filename to be in the FILE_EXT rather than nothing, unless the file name ends in '.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should leave off the square brackets when you are testing the exit code of a function, otherwise, you'll always get "true". Also, you should quote your variable. You could put an additional test for an empty extension as shown:

```
FILE_EXT=${FILE#*.}

if isNumeric "${FILE_EXT}" &&
    [ "${FILE_EXT}" != "${FILE}" -a "${FILE_EXT}" != "" ]
then
    echo "Numbered file."
fi
```

**Edit:** added test to handle filenames that end in "."

Comment: This doesn't account for files that end in '.'

Comment: Yes you should quote your variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
if [ isNumeric ${FILE_EXT:="no"} ]; then
    echo "Numbered file."
fi
```

If all you want to do is determine that the file has a numeric extension

The `${FILE_EXT:="no"}` will expand to either the value of FILE_EXT, or 'no' if FILE_EXT is null or empty.

Comment: False positive for filenames that consist only of digits since $FILE_EXT will contain the full filename if there is no dot at all.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `${FILE##*.}` with double "#" instead. also what do you mean the variable $FILE_EXT will be empty? if your file don't have extension, then when you do `${FILE#*.}` you will get the just file name in `FILE_EXT`. how is it empty ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ksh93, it should be possible to use it's own arithmetic.  But we need to be careful:
Just ((n)) will fail if n==0, so we test for ((n || !n)) which should always be true for any proper number.

To prevent ksh from exiting, we run the expression in a subshell ( ), adding spaces to prevent conflicts with the arithmetic expression (( ... )).

Finally, we close stderr with '2>& -' to prevent any error messages from non numeric arguments, although you might want to keep them in.

```
function isNumeric { 
  (
    typeset n=${1:?}
    ((n||!n))
  ) 2>& -
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[ -z "$1" ]` will test for an empty `$1`, as will `[ "" = "$1" ]`.

Or you could simply prepend a "0" to `$1` (i.e, `"0$1"`) to force it to be non-empty before checking if it is numeric (if you want empty extensions to be treated as numeric).

Answer (score 0):

I had some probs to run your script (Maybe that's because im using pdksh). So I have adjusted it slightly. Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

FILE=$1
FAILURE=1
SUCCESS=0

isNumeric ()
{
    if [ -n "$1" ]
    then
        case $1 in
            *[!0-9]* | "")
                echo "$1 not a number"
                return $FAILURE
            ;;
                       * )
                echo "$1 is a number"
                return $SUCCESS
            ;;
        esac
    else
        echo "parameter is empty"
        return $FAILURE
    fi
}

#...
FILE_EXT=${FILE#*.}
echo $FILE_EXT

isNumeric "${FILE_EXT}"
if [ "$?" = "0" ]
then
    echo "Numbered file."
fi
```